# Is there a Java's public LinkedListNode<E> class to store a temporary node

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a java's `LinkedList<Integer>` object. I want to temporarily store a node from this object in `LinkedListNode<Integer> tempNode`,  but I cannot seem to find this LinkedListNode class in Java docs.

Is there a way to store this node, with a Java library class or by some other technique? , without writing our own implementation.

Code:

```
public void method(LinkedList<Integer> list){
    LinkedListNode<Integer> tempNode = list.getFirst();  //<------- tempNode
    for( k times){ tempNode = tempNode.next();}
}
```

Comment: Why not assign it to a variable, or store the node in a new list if you need to store multiple?

Comment: I'd read the docs of `ListIterator` class in your case.

Comment: Sure, but I need to store a temporary node for the problem at hand. Code snippet is just for illustration purpose.

Comment: can't you just store the `Integer`?

Comment: @Henry I could, but I need the next pointers to rearrange the nodes. I don't think that's possible without a tempNode.

Comment: What about using a ListIterator? That lets you traverse the linked list at will, which is what you'd be able to do with the node. (edit: oops, just saw that Nagy Vilmos already mentioned that!)

Comment: @yshavit Let's just say I want to rearrange the nodes with O(1) space usage, not just traverse the list.

Comment: This question seems like it may be falling into the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have some problem, and you've skipped straight to a solution and are asking for help with it. I actually don't think that's bad per se -- it's great that you're trying to solve this yourself! -- but it may help us answer the question if we know more about the underlying problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @yshavit Sorry, I didn't think the details would matter. I want to merge two sorted lists using O(1) space. I started out with Java's LinkedList library class and I am stuck because I cannot find the public node class to store a tempNode.

Comment: Hmm, without seeing your approach specifically, I would think you could merge two LinkedLists by getting a ListIterator for both, and then using `next()` to traverse one and a combination of `next()` and `add(E)` to traverse-or-merge-into the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101248/discussion-between-charan-and-yshavit).